Will the frequency change when converting the ESP32 3.3 V logic to 5 V logic using a TXS0108E?
The GPIO on ESP32 (S3) are all 3.3 V logic. I want to control an ESC for a drone. The manufacturer says:

The ESC will use a standard 5 V PWM signal at 50 Hz between 1100 µs and 1950 µs. 3.3 V output may not read or cause misreads on the ESC.

If you have used the TXS0108E logic shifter, do you know if it will change my output frequency even if I programmed the output of the ESP32 to be 50 Hz like the manufacturer said?

No, a level shifter doesn't contain any logic ("intelligence") at all, so it cannot change the frequency of the signal. A level shifter has a maximum operating frequency, above which it may introduce noise into the signal or otherwise make it unusable, but that is far above the 50 Hz you need here (typically in the MHz range).

Thank you. Amazing

@ferer you can accept the answer (by clicking the tick symbol under the points counter) so that your question doesn't remain open.

The description about this particular level shifter is wrong. This level shifter does contain a lot of logic and intelligence to act as a bi-directional auto-direction sensing push-pull level shifter. Just look at the internal block diagram in the data sheet. It is not a passive level shifter.

@Justme I don't consider that logic (in the sense of "algorithmic logic"). I agree that the term might be missleading in the context of electronic design, though.

@PMF The chip must use some kind of algorithm to determine what it should do, how to react to changing inputs and based on inputs what actions should be done to update outputs.

The TSX0108E won't change your frequency, it can't do that.
However, it depends what you are trying to achieve and in what kind of environment, if the component is even suitable for that purpose. For example, most people here have asked why a TSX0108E or similar chip does not work properly in their design. If the chip is not used correctly in correct environment it will cause more problems than solve.
